# How to update data cakephp and get the affected rows

Tags: cakephp

I want to query sql like this:

```
update table set `status` = 2 where id=1 and `status`=1
```

And where get the affected rows.I find the [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/),
but how to update the `status` and use where in sql?
My cakephp version is 2.4.6.

update the resolved:
Now I make this function finally is:

```
public function updateById($id,$data,$status = ''){
    if( empty($id) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $conditions = array();
    $conditions['id'] = $id;
    if($status != ''){
        $conditions['status'] = $status;
    }
    $this->updateAll($data, $conditions);
    return $this->getAffectedRows();
```

And I call the function in my controller like this:

```
$this->MyModel->updateById(5, array('views'=>100,'status'=>2), 1);
```

That can make sure the record is update from `status` 1 to 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Update single field cakephp has method call

```
saveField()
```

[Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false)

Or you can use method call

```
updateAll()
```

[Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions)

For get affected rows cakephp has method call

`getAffectedRows()`

[Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getaffectedrows)